# Implicit conversions not working with type parameters

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, higher-kinded-types

I am having an issue with implicit conversions not working under certain circumstances (higher kinded types). Given a system, an expression type, and two specific expression sub types:

```
trait Sys[S <: Sys[S]]

object Expr {
  trait Var  [S <: Sys[S], A] extends Expr[S, A]
  trait Const[S <: Sys[S], A] extends Expr[S, A]
}
trait Expr[S <: Sys[S], A]
```

And a pimp class for expression operations:

```
class RichDoubleExpr[S <: Sys[S]](ex: Expr[S, Double]) {
  def gugu(): String = "yes"
}
```

Then let there be implicit conversions from primitives to expressions, and from expressions to expression ops:

```
implicit def const[S <: Sys[S]](d: Double): Expr[S, Double] = 
  new Expr.Const[S, Double] {}

implicit def exprOps[S <: Sys[S], A <% Expr[S, Double]](v: A): RichDoubleExpr[S] = 
  new RichDoubleExpr( v )
```

The following works (thus implicit method `const`):

```
3.4.gugu()
```

The following **does not** work (thus implicit method `exprOps`):

```
def test[S <: Sys[S]]: String = {
  val v = new Expr.Var[S, Double] {}
  v.gugu()
}
```

with the following error:

```
error: No implicit view available from java.lang.Object with
   Expr.Var[S,Double] => Expr[S,Double].
          v.gugu()
          ^
```

Now, since `Expr.Var` extends `Expr` and the type parameters are identical, that error message clearly doesn't make sense to me. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A viable solution in my case is to somewhat 'fix' type parameter `S`:

```
class ExprImplicits[S <: Sys[S]] {
  implicit def const(d: Double): Expr[S, Double] = new Expr.Const[S, Double] {}

  implicit def exprOps[A <% Expr[S, Double]](v: A): RichDoubleExpr[S] = 
    new RichDoubleExpr(v)
}
```

Now I can import the implicits for a particular system:

```
def test[S <: Sys[S]]: String = {
  val imp = new ExprImplicits[S]
  import imp._

  3.4.gugu()  // ok
  val v = new Expr.Var[S, Double] {}
  v.gugu()    // ok
}
```